# как json вывести строку J в html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

как в json вывести строку J в html

```
window.a = window.a || {
    b: {},
    c: {},
    d: {
        e: {
        }
    },

    f: {},
    g: {}
    ,h: {
        ,k: []
        ,l: []
        ,j: ['{"1": 2,"3": "4"  }}'
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: У вас одна скобка в j лишняя.

Comment: и J  в данном контексте не 'строка'

Comment: а как допустим вывести  2 элемент у J

Answer (score 3):

если убрать все лишнее, и вы хотите вывести текст `{"1": 2,"3": "4"}`

```
window.a = window.a || {
    b: {},
    c: {},
    d: {
        e: {}
    },
    f: {},
    g: {},
    h: {
        k: [],
        l: [],
        j: ['{"1": 2,"3": "4"}']
    }
};

alert(a.h.j);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdmez78w/ - демо

Для более детального ознакомления работы с объектами:

1. https://learn.javascript.ru/object
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: а как допустим вывести  2 элемент у J

Comment: @mr.robot, нет там второго элемента, строка это.

Comment: На самом деле это массив. Чтоб вывести  его, нужно преобразовать значение в объект. `JSON.parse(a.h.j[0])["3"]` выведет 4 https://jsfiddle.net/qdmez78w/1/